# mysql rds mutti az 5.6.40 --> 5.6.44 upgrade downtime

Tags: mysql

How much downtime would I expect on the mysql minor version upgrade for multi az rds?

I tested it on a single az read replica and there was about 5 minutes of downtime. How much can I expect on multi az?

There are 500 databases each with 100 tables if that makes any difference.

Comment: How much data, total?  How big is the largest table?  Since it is a "minor" upgrade, then _probably_ it will take under a minute.

Comment: 70gb 10g largest table. It took 5 minutes to upgrade single az read replica. Just wondering how long multi az will take